# QTimer not emitting signal at suggested interval

Tags: c++, qt

I have a simple setup to change a label on a timed interval, for testing purposes.  It seems that the signal does not ever get emitted.  I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with the Qt add-in.  Here is my setup...

```
Window::Window(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
    : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    my_label = new QLabel();

    timer = new QTimer(this);
    timer->setInterval(1000);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(nextFrame()));
}

void Window::nextFrame()
{
    static int i = 0;
    std::stringstream ss;

    ss << "C:/files/" << i << ".txt";
    QString qstr = QString::fromStdString(ss.str());
    ui.label->setText(qstr);

    ss.str("");
    i++;
    repaint();
}
```

And in the header file,

```
public:
    Window(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
    ~Window();

public slots:
    void nextFrame();

private:
    Ui::TrackerClass ui;
    QTimer *timer;
};
```

Why is the slot `nextFrame()` never being triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in this code which calls [`start()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html#start-2) and so based on this code `nextFrame()` would never be triggered by [`timeout()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html#timeout).

Comment: That's exactly it.  D'oh!  I was following a tutorial and missed that :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things I think I can help with:

1. nextFrame() is a SLOT.  SLOTs don't emit.  They receive.  SIGNALS emit.  Not trying to be rude, just want to be clear on this as it's an important distinction.  (in this case the signal is timeout() )
2. you need to have a start() to begin the timer.  something like the line below would seem to do the trick:

Hope this helps clear up some confusion.

```
timer->start(1000);
```